# Method App\Http\Controllers\SkillController::show does not exist. - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I keep getting this error, when I try to create a skill on my project

> Method App\Http\Controllers\SkillController::show does not exist.

[image]

I don't need a show() method because I don't need a show view of my skill object.

This is my route block look like

```
//Skill
Route::get('skill','SkillController@index');
Route::get('skill/create','SkillController@create');
Route::post('skill/store','SkillController@store');
Route::get('skill/{id}/edit', 'SkillController@edit');
Route::post('skill/{id}/update','SkillController@update');
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
```

This is my entire **SkillController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Skill;
use Input, View, File, Image, SSH, Redirect,Response;

class SkillController extends Controller {

    public function index(){

        $skills = Skill::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->where('img_path','==',NULL)->get();

        $first_color  = $skills[0]->color_code;
        $second_color = $skills[1]->color_code;
        $third_color  = $skills[2]->color_code;
        $fourth_color = $skills[3]->color_code;
        $fift_color   = $skills[4]->color_code;

        return View::make('layouts.be.skills.index', get_defined_vars());
    }

    public function all(){
        return Skill::all()->pluck('name');
    }

    public function create(){

        $skillTypes = ['Build System','Development Environment','Server Management','Operating System','IDE','Creative Suite','Video Editing','Package Management','Git Repository','Web Scaffolding','CSS Precompiler','Scripting','Framework','DBMS','Unit Test','Automation Testing','Cloud Platform','Hosting Provider','Content Management', 'API', 'Authentication' , 'Integration','Language','Web Server','Project Managment','Documentation','Utility','Network Analyzer' ];

        sort($skillTypes);

        return View::make('layouts.be.skills.create', get_defined_vars());
    }

    public function edit($id){

        $skillTypes = ['Build System','Development Environment','Server Management','Operating System','IDE','Creative Suite','Video Editing','Package Management','Git Repository','Web Scaffolding','CSS Precompiler','Scripting','Framework','DBMS','Unit Test','Automation Testing','Cloud Platform','Hosting Provider','Content Management', 'API', 'Authentication' , 'Integration','Language','Web Server','Project Managment','Documentation','Utility','Network Analyzer' ];

        sort($skillTypes);

        $skill = Skill::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('layouts.be.skills.edit', get_defined_vars());
    }

    public function store(){

        $skill             = new Skill;
        $skill->type       = Input::get('type');
        $skill->name       = Input::get('name');
        $skill->value      = Input::get('value');
        $skill->color_code = Input::get('color_code');
        $skill->save();

        if (Input::hasFile('logo_path')) {
            $image_path      = '/assets/img/skill/';
            $path            = public_path() . $image_path;
            $file            = Input::file('logo_path');
            $img_name        = $skill->id.'.png';
            $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($path, $img_name);
            $file_path       = $path . $img_name;
            $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
            $crop_file       = Image::make($file_path)->fit(20,20);
            $crop_file->save($path . 'crop-'.$img_name, 65);
        }else {
            $skill->img_path = Input::get('logo_path');
        }

        $skill->save();

        return Redirect::to('/skill') ->with('success','The skill was created succesfully!');

    }

    public function update($id){

        $inputs            = Input::all();
        $skill             = Skill::find($id);
        $skill->name       = Input::get('name');
        $skill->type       = Input::get('type');
        $skill->value      = Input::get('value');
        $skill->color_code = Input::get('color_code');

        $skill->save();

        if (Input::hasFile('logo_path')) {

            $image_path      = '/assets/img/skill/';
            $path            = public_path() . $image_path;
            $file            = Input::file('logo_path');
            $img_name        = $skill->id.'.png';
            $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($path, $img_name);
            $file_path       = $path . $img_name;
            $skill->img_path = $image_path . $img_name;
            $crop_file       = Image::make($file_path)->fit(20,20);
            $crop_file->save($path . 'crop-'.$img_name, 65);
        } else {
            $skill->img_path = Input::get('logo_path');
        }

        $skill->save();

        return Redirect::to('/skill') ->with('success','The skill was updated succesfully!');

    }

    public function destroy($id){

        $skill = Skill::find($id);
        $skill->delete();

        $image_path      = '/assets/img/skill/';
        $path            = public_path() . $image_path;
        File::deleteDirectory($path);

        return Redirect::to('/skill') ->with('success','The skill was deleted succesfully!');

    }

    public function skilldata(Request $request){
        $skill = str_replace("-"," ",$request->skill);
        $data = Skill::where(DB::raw('LOWER(type)'),'=',$skill)->get();
        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
}
```

I also tried this 2 commands already

```
┌──[root@bheng]──[/home/forge/bheng]                                                                         
└── php artisan cache:clear                                                                                  
Application cache cleared!                                                                                   

┌──[root@bheng]──[/home/forge/bheng]                                                                         
└── composer dumpauto                                                                                        
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details                         
Generating autoload files                                                                                    
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump                                                    
> @php artisan package:discover                                                                              
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon                                                                            
Discovered Package: laravel/slack-notification-channel                                                       
Discovered Package: laravel/nexmo-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/remote
Discovered Package: htmlmin/htmlmin
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Package manifest generated successfully.
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
┌──[root@bheng]──[/home/forge/bheng] 
└──
```

---

**skill.create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.be.master')
@section('content')


<div class="card-body card-padding">
    <div class="row">

        {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form', 'url'=>'skill/store','files' => true)) !!}


        <div class="col-sm-4">




            {{-- Name --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" value="{{Request::old('name')}}"  value="" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- Type --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="type" class="form-control">
                      @foreach($skillTypes as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item }}">{{ $item }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- Value --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Value</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <br>
                    <input type="range" id="range-value" value="93" name="value">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <h3 id="text-value"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>


            {{-- Color --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="color" name="color_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Color" id="example-color-input">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/skill"> Cancel </a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">



            {{-- Icon --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Icon</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <img name="logo_path" id="skill-icon" width="300px"><br><br>

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="logo_path" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                </div>


                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Icon URL </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <input id="url-logo" name="logo_path" type="text" class="form-control">

                </div>



            </div>

        </div>

        {!!Form::close()!!}


    </div>
</div>

@stop

@section('custom-scripts')

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Vibrant.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function readLogo(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#skill-icon').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        // Update media preview with base64 image
        $( "input[name*='logo_path']" ).change(function(){
            readLogo(this);
        });

        $( "#url-logo" ).on('keyup',function(){
            $('#skill-icon').attr('src', $( "#url-logo" ).val());
        });

        $('#text-value').text($('#range-value').val());
        $('#range-value').change(function(){
            $('#text-value').text($('#range-value').val());
        });

        // Icon
        var icon = $('#skill-icon');
        icon.attr('src', $( "#url-logo" ).val());

        $( "#url-logo" ).on('keyup',function(){

            var vibrant = new Vibrant(icon[0]);
            var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
            for (var swatch in swatches)
                if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
                    // console.log(swatches[swatch].getHex());
                    var color = swatches[swatch].getHex();
                    $( "input[name*='color_code']" ).val(color)
                    console.log('%c >>>>>>>>>>>>>>', "color:" + String(color) + ";");
                    console.log('color',color);

                    // Vibrant #3c62ac
                    // Muted #7484ab
                    // DarkVibrant #345cab
                    // DarkMuted #101010
                    // LightVibrant #849ccc

        });


    </script>
@stop
```

Please let me know if you spot anything I should not do.

Comment: Do you have a resource block in your routes file for skills? If so, it needs to go after the routes you've shown.

Comment: can you post your form from your view, chances are there is an error there, as it looks like your a using a get method - or have an incorrect action=""

Comment: @aynber I added on my post : https://i.imgur.com/VYTZSgM.png

Comment: @CodeBoyCode I updated my post with my view code `skill>create.blade.php`

Comment: @kyo you must have the route registered somewhere.  Do `artisan route:list`

Comment: @Devon try that I got `artisan: command not found`

Comment: @Devon Try **php artisan route:list** also, got this  `Class App\Http\Controllers\CommentController does not exist`

Comment: have you created a controller called CommentController ??

Comment: @CodeBoyCode:  I had some cache issue. I got my route to display now, will update the post for you.

Answer (score 3):

It just route ordering issue.

Make Route Order Like This :

```
//Skill
Route::post('skill/store','SkillController@store');
Route::get('skill','SkillController@index');
Route::get('skill/create','SkillController@create');
Route::post('skill/{id}/update','SkillController@update');
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
Route::get('skill/{id}/edit', 'SkillController@edit');
```

OR

If your making CRUD module then use Laravel 'Resource Controllers' routing method https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

First Create Resource Controller : Run Below command In terminal

```
php artisan make:controller SkillController --resource
```

Then Put Below Line In 'routes/web.php' file

```
Route::resource('skill', 'SkillController');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a method= on your 
And that is why assume Route::resource set up it will assume you're trying to access the show method.

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'POST'))
```

Comment: I disagree. `Form::open` will use `POST` by default.

Comment: Also Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` into the form

Comment: @kyo Agree , Try to add csrf token in form

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as I thought in my initial comment, you haven't specified an action for the form - this should resolve your issues:

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form', 'url'=>'skill/store', 'action' => 'SkillController@store' ,'files' => true)) !!}
```

also, your routes are incorrect - your routes should be:

```
Route::get('skill','SkillController@index');
Route::get('skill/create','SkillController@create');
Route::post('skill/store','SkillController@store');
Route::get('skill/{id}/edit', 'SkillController@edit');
Route::patch('skill/{id}/update','SkillController@update'); //this should be put or patch not post
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
```

Comment: Laravel Form::open() By default, a POST method will be assumed; however, you are free to specify another method:

Answer (score 0):

if you already manually wrote routes like this

```
//Skill
Route::get('skill','SkillController@index');
Route::get('skill/create','SkillController@create');
Route::post('skill/store','SkillController@store');
Route::get('skill/{id}/edit', 'SkillController@edit');
Route::post('skill/{id}/update','SkillController@update');
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
```

then you dont need this one, this code should be somewhere on your routes

```
Route::resource('skills','SkillController');
```

or

you can remove your entire manual written routes of skillcontroller

change it into this one

```
Route::resource('skills', 'SkillController', ['only'=> ['index','create','store','delete','edit','update']]);
```

Comment: @kyo you need to choose either of using route::resource with only or write it manually like yours